# Cannot compile resource for application manifest in C++ Builder 2006

Tags: c++, manifest, embedded-resource, c++builder-2006

I am trying to add the application manifest to a program built with C++Builder 2006, by following this [article](http://www.lnssoftware.ca/blog/?p=113).

*(The manifest is to obtain admin rights for my program, which contains "setup" in his name and so it triggers the “This program may not have installed correctly” warning).*

I have the **MyApp_Setup.exe.manifest** in the project folder, along with the **MyApp_Setup1.rc** file, which is present in the project.

When i try to build, i get:

> [RC Fatal Error] MyApp_Setup1.rc(1): File creation failed

What i'm doing wrong, or what should I do?

*question edited 'cause i messed up the filenames and the output error didn't matched*

Comment: Your error message does not match your shown filename.  `MyApp_Setup1.rc` would produce `MyApp_Setup1.res`, whereas `MyApp1.rc` would produce `MyApp1.res`. In any case, if the output `.res` file is already present, make sure it is not read-only (such as if it has been checked in to a VCS system).

Comment: Ok, i messed up while writing the question, edited.
About the RES file, i had the same intuition, so i deleted it completly before the build command. Nothing changed: C++Builder compiles the sources and then fails at the resource file creation. No .RES file are created, so it stops before the RES file creation step.I wonder what that (1) in the error message (MyApp_Setup1.rc(1)) means....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

In the project options I always set an "_obj" output folder, but the resource compiler **WANTS** an **existing** "debug_build" folder to write the .res file.
It don't create the directory, hence the error in the file creation.
If i remove the "Obj" option, or once you have the "Debug_Build" folder present, everything compiles.